# Check if given DateTime is today - undesirable timezone offset

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I have some moment in time in UTC timestamp. I create a DateTime object from it, and then try to enrich it with "(today)" or "(tomorrow)" explanation if it is so:

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime(this.timeUtc, DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.mediumDate();

String resultingString = dateTimeUtc.withZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()))
    .toString(dateTimeFormatter);

if(dateTimeUtc.getDayOfYear() == DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).getDayOfYear()) {
    resultingString += " (" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.today_caption) + ")";
} else if(dateTimeUtc.getDayOfYear() == DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).plusDays(1).getDayOfYear()) {
    resultingString += " (" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.tomorrow_caption) + ")";
}
```

But - surprisingly - my app does a TimeZone conversion somewhere. Device is set for eastern europian time (GMT+3 currently) and it works like this: 2 june 2:59 AM is treated like today (0_o) 2 june 3:01 is already a tomorrow.

Can someone point to an error?

P. S.: if there's a better way to qualify DateTime as 'today' or 'tomorrow' - I would be great to see any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no answer provided, I'll post workaround of my own. Though still have no idea why comparison of two UTC-zoned timestamp'ed days of year gives user's timezone offset.

Here's the code that works correctly for me:

```
if(dateTimeUtc.withZone(userZone).getDayOfYear() == DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).withZone(userZone)
        .getDayOfYear()) {
    resultingString += " (" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.today_caption) + ")";
    } else if(dateTimeUtc.withZone(userZone).getDayOfYear() == DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).withZone(userZone)
        .plusDays(1).getDayOfYear()) {
    resultingString += " (" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.tomorrow_caption) + ")";
}
```

this produces correct check if given day is in interval from now till start of tomorrow or from start of tomorrow till start of the day after.